# What is the meaning of 'as' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The family are excited about their new life, but others have arrived with less of a sense of starting something good **as** fleeing something bad.

Please could you tell me the reason for using 'as' in this sentence and the grammar behind it.

Comment: It's a mistake - it should be _less...than_.

Comment: Quite possibly conflating 'less A than B' with 'less as A, more as B'. '... others have arrived seeing it less as starting something good, more as fleeing something bad.'

Comment: The sentence needs to use the idiomatic [not so much](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/not-so-much-sth-as-sth) in place of *less*: *The family are excited about their new life, but others have arrived with not so much of a sense of starting something good as fleeing something bad.*